# Is it possible to sum range type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder if it is possible to sum documents with range type to the largest ranges?

I have the following documents with integer_range:

```
{"range": {"gte": 0, "lt": 10}},
{"range": {"gte": 10, "lt": 25}}, 
{"range": {"gte": 30, "lt": 40}},
{"range": {"gte": 40, "lt": 60}}
```

and I would like to get the result:

```
{"gte": 0, "lt": 25},
{"gte": 30, "lt": 60}
```

Is there a query that can do this?

Comment: can you explain how you derive the result you expect?

Comment: Sorry for misleading - I would like to get such a result.
That is, from the ranges:
0-10,
0-5,
10-15,
20-30

I would like to get:
0-15,
20-30

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how your sample documents relate to this